# How to create a responsive div with a background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this responsive html&css code

```
<div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox1"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.ibox{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;      
    border:1px solid red;
    max-width:100%;
}

.ibox1{
    width:100px;
    height:90px;      
    border:1px solid yellow;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
    max-width:40%;
}

.ibox2{
    width:80px;
    height:25px;      
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px;
    max-width:40%;
}
```

how can I add a responsive image background for box1 and box2?

for example here is a demo before add background:

[jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/jq3y3oab/5/)

also I don't want size limitation so
I tried remove size limitation and add backgrounds....but it seems wrong4

[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/jq3y3oab/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this more what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jq3y3oab/7/

I added

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

so that the relative values of `.ibox` don't collapse to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this, I guess its what you want

```css
<style>
.ibox{
    width:100%;
    height:90px;      
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align: left;
}

.ibox1{
    width:50%;
    height:88px;      
    float:right;
    background: red;
    margin: 1px;
    
}

.ibox2{
    width:49%;
    float: left;
    height:28px;      
    background: blue;
    margin: 1px;
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 568px) {

.ibox1{
    width: 100%;
    height:90px;      
    float:left;
    background: red;
    
}

.ibox2 {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}

.ibox{
    width:100%;
    height:182px;      
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align: left;
}

}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox1"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
    <div class="ibox2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the following properties in your CSS

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I altered your fiddle a bit, hope this helps!!!

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/jq3y3oab/11/)